# Why does my JS silently die?

Tags: javascript, dom

Okay, so I wrote this just under a decade ago:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/color-blend/

I'm pretty sure it worked okay at the time, but since then (or, who knows, maybe always) a bug has crept in.  I can demonstrate it like so:

1. Stay in 'hex'.  Pick a couple of colors.  Blend them.
2. Edit the hex colors with the keyboard (that is, type in new hex values, or alter the ones that are there).  Blend again.
3. So far so good.
4. Switch the mode to "RGB".
5. Edit one of the numbers.
6. Now nothing works—no blending, no type switching, nothing.

Why?  I even can't figure out where it's failing.

(Yes, I know the JS is clumsy as hell and uses global variables and all kinds of ick.  I do plan to rewrite it.  But first I need to understand what's going wrong here, and if at all possible how I should have diagnosed it myself.  Please note that I just barely understand how to use, in a very basic way and probably not properly, the Firefox JS debugger.)

Comment: Bring up the dev tools in chrome or firebug in ff and see what you see.

Comment: I'll need a little more guidance than that.

Comment: Any chance we could see a nicely formatted version of the (javascript) code?

Comment: You need to debug, unless kind soul cares to do it for you.

Comment: Nico, I already consider it to be nicely formatted, so it’s hard for me to guess what you’re seeking.

Comment: bmargulies, perhaps you missed the part where I said I’m barely able to use the debugger.  Asking some kind soul to help me figure out how to do this, if not do it themselves, is really the entire point of the post.

Comment: My bad, Chrome's view source was ignoring the line breaks. IE9's version is much nicer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a case-insensitive switch on your regex in colorParse().

You .toUpperCase the color... so 'rgb' goes to 'RGB' but then your regex tries to replace lowercase 'rgb' which it can't do.

col = c.replace(/[#rgb(]*/i, '');

Notice the /i in the regex to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Holy… that makes a ton of sense.  Now, the real question is: why am I uppercasing the text?  I can’t think of a single reason why that’s a good idea.  I’ll /i the regexp regardless, but I should look to see if I can also stop flipping case.  Hang on a moment while I test that out.

Comment: Hey everybody... I found this bug by running Eric's code through the built in Pretty Printer in Chrome (Sources tab... { } icon at the bottom), making a local copy from that, and just putting in a couple console.log() statements to see what things were returning.

Comment: @Eric, you probably added the `toUpperCase()` to standardize the RGB prefix before you removed it. Your users might enter it in various cases.